# npm start issues for feathers.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have created two different feathersJS app, but when I run npm start in both app it gives me two different typeserror. how to resolve this issue?
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbFe9.png)
[image][image]

Comment: If you go into your package.json do you see, under "scripts"  "start"

Comment: and your second you might just need to do npm install?

Comment: so, do you have father issue :)? Ok, joking apart, just **read the errors**. It looks like you don't have winston module. Try `npm install` or `npm install winston`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first one, you're likely missing a start script in your `package.json` file. There should be a data structure in that file that looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "..."
}
```

And you likely need to modify it to start the app in whatever way you want:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "...",
  "start": "your start script here" // usually something like node server.js
}
```

To fix the issue in the second one, just `npm install winston`

Comment: I have opened package.json I have the following file                                       **{
  "name": "feathers-basics",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}**

Comment: @user3514377 Yeah, just like Alex said. You have a `"test"` script but not a `"start"` script.